# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/{path}" - error: "The operation

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I am loading an HTML file into my app and displaying some information to the user. The HTML file is part my app Bundle Resources. I have noticed in the console the following error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/{somePath}/" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file"
```

So then, I have added to my info.plist the following key:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>file</string>
</array>
```

and I get a different error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/{somePath}/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

Even though I am getting this error, I am able to open the HTML file without any issues.

Do you guy have any hints how to solve this error?

Comment: You don't need a URL scheme for accessing your own app's `Bundle`. What code produces that error?

Comment: loading a file from bundle doesn't require any specifications in info.plist file. you can access it directly as : 
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "intro", ofType: "html")

Comment: I am using this method:  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url). I have commented it out and no more error :)

Comment: just to clarify, canOpenURL(url) was implemented in this method: func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) { }

Comment: @pickleRick Can you tell me how did you solved it ? I did not understand where did you commented out

Comment: @ugrdursun Well, I just do not use `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` in order to load a file.html from the app's `Bundle`. Looking at the app source code, I just use `loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL) -> WKNavigation?`  Adding a WKWebView as a subview in a UIView, then you just need to call `wkWebView.loadFileURL(url:, readAccessURL:)` giving the proper start  url and base url.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer but actually i am using react-native and rn webview; could not even understand which methods you talking about :/

Comment: ah ok, mmmh I don't have experience with React-Native, sorry . I'm using Swift. Anyway I'm talking about this method [loadfileurl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl)

Comment: I found the solution. I converted my html file to "clean version" and it worked. You can search google as clean html converters. I hope this help someone.

Comment: @ugrdursun I've googled `clean html converters` but I got a bit puzzled by the results. So I think it would be really cool if you could add the resource/tool that you used. Even better if you could add an answer with proper step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
      />
```

*`originWhitelist={['*']}`* resolved my problem